# Unity 5.6.3 internal editor error

Tags: unity-game-engine, editor

i just made clean install of Unity **5.6.3p1**(i need it) and the editor is crashing in a loop with error:

```
IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
UnityEditor.SceneRenderModeWindow.GetGUIContent (DrawCameraMode drawCameraMode) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Annotation/SceneRenderModeWindow.cs:356)
UnityEditor.SceneView.DoToolbarGUI () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/SceneView/SceneView.cs:530)
UnityEditor.SceneView.OnGUI () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/SceneView/SceneView.cs:1502)
System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:222)
```

Making editor unusable.

I have no idea why its pointing to "C:/buildslave/.." when i have no such directory.

Maybe someone had this error and knows how to solve it?

Comment: What happens if you double click on the error?